# NGINX + Passenger Deployment of Redmine -- 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, redmine

Seen this question asked a few times, tried out several posted solutions without any luck.

installed phusion passenger w/ nginx, running ruby 1.9.3 under a multi-user rvm install

somewhat familiar with nginx and deployment of python apps through uwsgi -- this one has me stumped

My nginx vhost config is pasted below:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name EXAMPLE.COM;

    access_log /home/redmine/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /home/redmine/logs/nginx_error.log;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    keepalive_timeout 120;

    root /home/redmine/redmine-repo/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

}
```

for reference static files are being served correctly

for example when I try to visit:
    http://EXAMPLE.COM/images/duplicate.png

it shows up just fine -- I've set the entire /home/redmine directory to 
    chmod -R 0777 /home/redmine

thinking I'm missing something on the config side -- any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Check your application, show us logs and tell the number error you're getting on your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly problem - simple solution once I tracked down the right ference

I had selected to perform a custom install of nginx with passenger
when doing so it did not add the

```
passenger_root
passenger_ruby
```

variables to nginx.conf so passenger was not being initialized

hope this helps someone running into the same issue

Comment: If this is resolved, please mark it as such. Thanks and welcome to [sf].

Answer (score 2):

If all the folder and file permission are set correctly, please check the configuration under nginx.conf:

```
location ~ ^/redmine(/.*|$) {
   passenger_base_uri /redmine;
   passenger_app_root /Users/cc/Dropbox/Work/www/redmine;
   passenger_enabled on;
}
```

You should have at least these three lines to enable redmine to work.

Comment: `passenger_app_root` was the key for me, because of the way I had `root` setup (as a symlink)